# How to separate JSON array into 2 separate arrays of values with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have the following AJAX script pulling in a JSON array from a PHP file:

```
// get jsonData from inc/wip-data.php
var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url: 'inc/wip-data.php',
  dataType: 'json',
});
```

The JSON array is as follows:

```
[
{
    "date": "2015-10",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2015-11",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-01",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-02",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-03",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-04",
    "clientCostsTotal": "27962.50"
},
{
    "date": "2016-05",
    "clientCostsTotal": "174060.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-06",
    "clientCostsTotal": "309000.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-07",
    "clientCostsTotal": "502261.50"
},
{
    "date": "2016-08",
    "clientCostsTotal": "7598.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-12",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}
]
```

I need to grab all of the `date` values and store them in one array. Also, I need to grab all of the `clientCostsTotal` values and store them in a separate array. How do I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), with your array of objects there are several [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that could do this but try using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for each required new array. jQuery also has similar methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery, use a [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```
var dates = [];
var clientCosts = [];

$.ajax({
  url: 'inc/wip-data.php',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    dates.push(item.date);
    clientCosts.push(item.clientCostsTotal);
  });
});
```

For a more functional approach, you might want to try using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which gives you the ability to generate multiple result arrays while still iterating through the source data only once. Here's a function implemented using `.reduce()` that will take any array structured like you have it and collate those results into a result. This function is generic, would work for any property names defined in the source.

```js
function collate(d) {
  return d.reduce(function(prev, cur, index) {
    var ret = {};
    for (var prop in cur) {
      if (index === 0) {
        ret[prop] = [];
      } else {
        ret[prop] = prev[prop];
      }
      ret[prop].push(cur[prop]);
    }
    return ret;
  }, {});
}

var data = [{
  "date": "2015-10",
  "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}, {
  "date": "2015-11",
  "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-01",
  "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-02",
  "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-03",
  "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04",
  "clientCostsTotal": "27962.50"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05",
  "clientCostsTotal": "174060.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-06",
  "clientCostsTotal": "309000.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-07",
  "clientCostsTotal": "502261.50"
}, {
  "date": "2016-08",
  "clientCostsTotal": "7598.00"
}, {
  "date": "2016-12",
  "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}];

var reduced = collate(data);
console.log(reduced.date, reduced.clientCostsTotal);
```

Comment: I am getting a console error at `jsonData.forEach(function(item) {` that says "charts-test.php:443 Uncaught TypeError: jsonData.forEach is not a function". How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the function in a callback once the data has came back? Or are you calling the function right away before the data has arrived?

Comment: Your AJAX call is not actually returning the JSON, but the jQuery [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. You need to add a `.done()` callback like in the edited answer.

Comment: @dave I see. That makes sense. Thank you so much. Why am I receiving a console error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." due to the period in the `.done(function(data) {` line?

Comment: I think there was an extra comma in there before, see the update.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for your help @dave

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `.map`? It will save having to assign a whole new array and push to it?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'inc/wip-data.php',
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(data) {
  // One for dates
  var dates = data.map(function(item) {
    return item.date;
  });

  // The other for client costs
  var clientCostTotals = data.map(function(item) {
    return item.clientCostsTotal;
  });
});
```

Comment: Because that only creates one array as a result, not two

Comment: Good spot. Updated.

Comment: That works, but now you're looping the array twice instead of once. `forEach()` or a simple loop is just a better fit for this situation.

Comment: I would argue not. Two reasons. Firstly the code here is more functional than using a `forEach()`. I don't need to forward declare anything and therefor maintenance is easier. I'm also not muting the array. Second with modern browsers your never going to notice any performance hit when looping an array that has been returned by a server. Your only ever going to have a trivial sized array. I would prefer more readable code in this situation. `map()` provides that more than `forEach()` IMO.

Comment: Well, I can agree with you about setup and maintenance, but I'm not willing to just throw performance out the window. Perhaps the best solution is an implementation using `Array.reduce()` which retains the functional design of `.map()`, but also avoids duplicate iterations through the source data.

Comment: Performance has been considered. Even in an older browser there would be zero impact to the user by looping a 11 element array twice. A user would never notice this. We might be talking less than a millisecond difference in the current version of chrome. I would be more concerned with how the DOM will be updated after the two arrays have been created.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery solution

```
// Your data will look like
var dataArrayOfJson = [{"date": "2015-10", "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"},{"date": "2015-11","clientCostsTotal": "0.00"}];

var dates = [], clientCostsTotals= [];
$(dataArrayOfJson ).each( function(i,item){ 
  dates.push(dataArrayOfJson [i].date);  // or dates.push(item.date);
  clientCostsTotals.push(dataArrayOfJson [i].clientCostsTotal); // or  clientCostsTotals.push(item.clientCostsTotal);
});
```

Comment: I am getting a console error at `dates.push(data[i].date);  // or dates.push(item.date);` that says "charts-test.php:445 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined". How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry update the example was testing with different var name `data`

Answer (score 0):

A new solution that I've been using is the[***map***](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. It is developed for functional programming, a better way to split the "trees", and much more understandable. Still learning but I recommend this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-5obm1G_FY). It's fully supported by ECMA 5.

```
var Array1 = 
[
{
    "date": "2015-10",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2015-11",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-01",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-02",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-03",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-04",
    "clientCostsTotal": "27962.50"
},
{
    "date": "2016-05",
    "clientCostsTotal": "174060.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-06",
    "clientCostsTotal": "309000.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-07",
    "clientCostsTotal": "502261.50"
},
{
    "date": "2016-08",
    "clientCostsTotal": "7598.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-12",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}];

var result = Array1.map(function(a) {
var dates = [], clientCostsTotals= [];
dates.push(a.date); 
clientCostsTotals.push(a.clientCostsTotal);
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I think you need to need to read the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) documentation again.

Comment: What's the point of using `.map()` if you don't have a `return` statement in the function? `result` will be full of `undefined` values.

Comment: If you don't return anything, you might as well just use `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use lodash for operations involving arrays. The [lodash api has a function called map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map) which meets your requirements nicely. Here is an example:

```
var jsonArray = [
{
    "date": "2015-10",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2015-11",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
},
{
    "date": "2016-01",
    "clientCostsTotal": "0.00"
}];
var dateValues = _.map(jsonArray, 'date');
var clientTotalCostValues = _.map(jsonArray, 'clientCostsTotal');
console.log('dateValues = ', dateValues);
console.log('clientTotalCostValues = ', clientTotalCostValues );
```

Outputs the following:

```
dateValues =  ["2015-10", "2015-11", "2016-01"]
clientTotalCostValues =  ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
```

You can test it out quickly for yourself by going to the [lodash api docs page](https://lodash.com/docs/) open your browsers dev tools and paste my code snippet into the console and hit enter.